# AdSense info only partially shown on Analytics - setDomainName()?

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

A long while ago we've linked our AdSense and Analytics accounts but haven't used AdSense in some years. Now we've started an AdSense campaign but trying to view it on Analytics only shows a fragment of the real revenues shown on AdSense.
Google has an answer on https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6090771?hl=en in which the relevant clause is likely:

> Are you using the "_udn" variable or the "setDomainName()" function in
>   your Analytics code?
>
> Use of this functionality in Analytics requires a corresponding change
>   to your AdSense code.

But they don't explain how the AdSense code should be modified. Following the link suggested there also doesn't provide that information.
You can see our code on http://colnect.com

In Analytics, the correct view ( colnect.com ) is associated with the AdSense account. Both platforms report the link to be valid and passing information.

If any AdSense code is needed, what could it be?
If not, anything else we might have been missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Upon upgrading to Universal Analytics, seems the problem has passed.

Upgrade guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/guide

Cross domain tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain